# How to extract numbers from data in table using regular expression in sparksql query

Tags: python, sql, regex, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a table, It has a column called `actual_result` which has data in this format

Sample data from `actual_result` column, each row value is separated by pipe delimiter below:

```
> actual_result
++
|{"count": 0}  
|{"count": 0} 
|{"data_dt": "20230101"}  
|{"count": 0}     
|{"count": 0}    
|{"count": 0}
|{"az_cust_id": 0, "percent_null": 0}
|{"ndc": 0}
|{"az_prod_id": 0, "percent_null": 0}
|{"sp_nm": 0, "percent_null": 0}
|{"az_mkt_id": 0, "percent_null": 0}
|{"cust_zip": 0, "percent_null": 0}
|{"file_typ": 0, "percent_null": 0}
|{"ndc": 0, "percent_null": 0}
|{"zs_drug_cd": 0, "percent_null": 0}
|{"az_brd_id": 0, "percent_null": 0}
|{"prod_nm": 0, "percent_null": 0}
|{"mkt_nm": 0, "percent_null": 0}  
|{"ther_area_nm": 0, "percent_null": 0}   
|{"prod_lvl": 0, "percent_null": 0}   
|{"pueblo_exc_brd_ind": 0, "percent_null": 0}  
|{"invc_no": 0}          
|{"kaiser_ind": 0, "percent_null": 0}   
|{"fld_exc_ind": 0, "percent_null": 0}   
|{"sd_nm": 0}     
|{"tot_sls_units": 0}
```

I want the output to be in this format

> `(0,0)`

I have tried using `regexp_extract` and all json functions but I'm either getting null values or no results. can anyone help me with this? this is one of the sample code that i had tried but this is giving null values.

```py
sql_df = spark.sql("""
    SELECT 
        *,
        REGEXP_EXTRACT(actual_result, '\\d+') AS extracted_numbers
    FROM schema.table
    WHERE actual_result LIKE '%:%'
""")
sql_df.show(10,0)
```

Comment: Convert the string into json and read the values. https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-from_json-convert-json-column-to-struct-map-or-multiple-columns-2/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the signature of `regexp_extract`:

> `def regexp_extract(e: Column, exp: String, groupIdx: Int): Column`

It needs a third parameter that indicates:

- to take all the matching pattern if `groupIdx=0`
- to take the i-th group if `groupIdx=i` and `i>0`, a group being a regex defined between parenthesis.

You also need to prefix the regex string with `r`, otherwise `\d` is not recognized or use `[0-9]`.

In your case, you can write your query as follows:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, '{"prod_id": 12, "percent_null": 34}'),
    (2, '{"prod_id": 0, "percent_null": 0}')
], ['id', 'actual_result'])
df.createOrReplaceTempView("table")

spark.sql("""
    select actual_result, struct(
        regexp_extract(actual_result, '([0-9]+)[^0-9]*([0-9]+)', 1) as prod_id,
        regexp_extract(actual_result, '([0-9]+)[^0-9]*([0-9]+)', 2) as percent_null
    ) as extracted_numbers from table
""").show(truncate=False)
```

```
+-----------------------------------+-----------------+
|actual_result                      |extracted_numbers|
+-----------------------------------+-----------------+
|{"prod_id": 12, "percent_null": 34}|{12, 34}         |
|{"prod_id": 0, "percent_null": 0}  |{0, 0}           |
+-----------------------------------+-----------------+
```

NB: you could also use `from_json` as follows:

```py
spark.sql("""
    select from_json(
         actual_result,
         'struct<prod_id:STRING, percent_null:DOUBLE>'
    ) as extracted_numbers
    from table
""").show()
```

```
+-----------------+
|extracted_numbers|
+-----------------+
|       {12, 34.0}|
|         {0, 0.0}|
+-----------------+
```

Comment: thanks a lot for providing help. However the json method would not work because the column names that you have provided will vary in each row data value in the table. There is no defined values in json data. this will give accurate answer only for single row value. for the first solution i'm still getting no result. it seems like reg expression is not able to identify the number inside this value.

Comment: That's strange, it works for me. Try replacing `\d` by `[0-9]`. What version of spark are you using?

Comment: i tried replacing \d with [0-9] as well, it's still not picking digits from inside the data. I assume it has something to with how the digits is stored. the spark version i'm using is '2.4.6-amzn-0'

Comment: What is the schema of the table? (or at least the type of actual result)

Comment: actual result column is of string type.

Comment: What do you obtain with `regexp_extract(actual_result, '([0-9]+)[^0-9]*([0-9]+)', 0)` ?

Comment: I tried running this, this is giving me a null value in the column.

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the result of `spark.table("schema.table").select("actual_result").show()`? It feels like we are missing something...

Comment: i have added sample data in the body of the question. this column has majorly null values, there are ~200 rows which have this json format data from where i want to fetch the desired values i.e (value of json ) which will look like (0,0)

Comment: Have you tried running my exact code? (data creation included, just for testing)